# Trouble with a checkbox inside a div with a dynamic height, how to do?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've got a lot of trouble with getting my checkboxes vertical aligned in my divs with a dynamic height.

I have some of my view:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="row recent-information">
            <div class="product-navigation">
                <div class="product-header-text">
                    <div class="col-md-3 product-details">
                        <p>Product name</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 product-details">
                        <p>Note</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 product-details">
                        <p>Price</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 product-details">
                        <p>Stock</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
            {
                <div class="product-header">
                    <div class="product-header-text">
                        <div class="col-md-3 product-details-entity">
                            <h6>@item.Name</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 product-details-entity">
                            <h6>@item.Description</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 product-details-entity">
                            <h6>@item.Price DKK</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 product-details-entity">
                            <h6>@item.Stock</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 product-details-checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBox("naem", new { @class = "products-checkbox" })
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the style:

```
 .product-header {
    min-height: 7%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    overflow: hidden;

}

    .product-header-text {
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    height: 100%;
}

.product-details {
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.product-details-entity {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: auto;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    background: #f8f8f5;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin-top: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 65px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-image: url("../Images/checkmark2.png");
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
}
```

My problem is, that my divs, the product-details are dynamically based on the content from the database, and I can't get my checkboxes to follow.

Comment: Can you build a jsFiddle for us so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Have you tried using `vertical-align:top;` or `position:relative; top:0;`?